# Pasting spreadsheet into document woe's

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I'm trying to paste a few cells from my spreadsheet into my document. The problem is that the spreadsheet never fits correctly into the document, even though all the cells are smaller than the space available in the document (yes, including width-wise). So there should be plenty of room for it to fit, but some cells are changed when pasted into the document to be wider and others narrower.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Could you paste a screenshot of the problem? It would also help if you could share the document itself, but it's perfectly understandable if you don't want to do that.

Comment: Both are available for public viewing. On the documents, scroll down to the bottom to see where I pasted it. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGbDZHw4W3se3twQSe3eTc19rjLF2GUUcYXlF8aeNGw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmbCSSHfSlcsdHZHU2tGbUM3TmlLcGJkbHM2UDZjeXc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I do not get what the fuss is about. Here's a snip from the spreadsheet:

[image: WA54748 first example]

and here is a snip from the the document after copy and pasting the above:

[image: WA54748 second example]

This is a snip of part of what OP shows in link to document in Comment:

[image: WA54748 third example]

Maybe something has changed since the Q was posted.